# AbstractUIPlugin error and Missing tabs in plugin.xml from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I checked in eclipse/java plugin project from svn repository.
Eclipse automatically builds the code to show hundreds of errors.

[image]
It seems like that eclipse doesn't properly link to the plugin libraries. Googling to find [this site](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/plugin_dev/) that I need dependencies and other tabs in plugin.xml.

[image]

What might be wrong? I use Indogo(3.7) on Mac OS X 10.7.4

Comment: Was there a .classpath file in the root of the project on the server in addition to the .project file?  How exactly did you check the project out from SVN?

Comment: Also, if it's using AbstractUIPlugin it's a PDE project.  Was the `.project` file imported correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Indigo (3.7) for my Mac, but it happened so that the plugin was built on Helios (3.6). When I run the plugin using Helios, I got the project compiled without errors.

It seems like that some of the plugins are (heavily) version dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got the base XML editor instead of the plugin.xml editor.

This is probably caused by your not having the eclipse plugin development environment (PDE) enabled in a new workspace.

Try creating a new plugin project (this will enable the necessary plugin tools), or go to the preferences and enable the "correct" capability.  Since the capabilities seem to change from release to release, I always use the first method and then delete the new project.

Comment: PDT is the PHP Development Tools.  Either way, the editor being used would be unrelated to which Errors are shown in the Problems View.

Comment: @nitind: Corrected my abbreviation - got it confused with the JDT.  Anyway, I have seen this before where some capabilities are by default turned off for a new workspace and you get compile errors because they're not being put in the eclipse classpath container.  Creating a new project with a targeted New Wizard would automatically enable the capability and cause the required plugin jars to be put into the eclipse classpath container.